# Why can't I see all regions when creating a stack set?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am using AWS Stack Sets to deploy resources to multiple accounts and regions.  When the console presents the list of regions to include, I don't see all regions.  The option for "Add all Regions" will add a bunch, not not actually *all* regions.  For example, in my region selector at the top right I see regions that include **Asia Pacific (Hong Kong), EU (Stockholm) and Middle East (Bahrain)**.  But those don't show up as options when selecting the Stack Set regions nor when selecting "Add all regions," even when I am deploying to the same account I am in.  And even when I've enabled those regions for my account.  Why can't I see/pick them?

**What do I need to do to make them show up so I can deploy there using Stack Sets?**

Maybe I am just missing something when I review https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/global-infrastructure/regional-product-services/ but I see those regions checked for AWS CloudFormation.  And the [recent notice about the Hong Kong region](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/now-open-aws-asia-pacific-hong-kong-region/) lists Cloudformation as well.

Comment: Does your template contain resources that are not yet available in those regions? Just because CloudFormation is supported in that region, does not mean the resources in the template can be created in the region.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually because they don't support stack sets yet in some regions. What makes it worse is adding support seems to take a really long time (approaching a year now for eu-north-1) and AWS don't announce when this might be fixed.

There's a thread on the AWS support forum regarding this where I've posted a comment too:

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=916277

Comment: Ah, this makes sense.  It surprised me since their regional support page shows CloudFormation as checked for all these regions, but apparently it is not _full_ support in all regions at this time: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/global-infrastructure/regional-product-services/

Answer (score 0):

"New" AWS regions (including Hong Kong, Bahrain and Stockholm) are disabled by default.

If you wish to use these regions, you will need to enable them within the account.

See: [Setting permissions to enable accounts for upcoming AWS Regions | AWS Security Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/setting-permissions-to-enable-accounts-for-upcoming-aws-regions/)

Comment: I mentioned I have already done that, but the regions still aren't listed.

Comment: From what I can observe in my AWS accounts, Stockholm is enabled by default, and was the last enabled-by-default region. Regardless, it is disappointing for a new region to launch without StackSets, It is especially disappointing that `eu-north-1` has been online for a year and still does not have it.

Comment: I just found out that today (some time missed huh) Stockholm for example is still not on the list. How hard that can be if CFN is already supported, and access is granted via IAM roles?
I am a big AWS native fan, but now seriously considering switching to terraform.